# Как в application.yaml добавить параметр к значению

Tags: java, spring, yaml

Есть application.yaml со значением

```
redirectToProjectURl:"https://URL/#/redirectPage?projectRedirect&projectId=10&clientId=20"
```

Я использую данную ссылку в сервисе и хочу подставлять в параметры свои значения, но не могу понять как мне это сконфигурировать в файле? Есть вариант сделать вот так:

```
redirectToProjectURl:"https://URL/#/redirectPage?projectRedirect&projectId={pId}&clientId={cId}"
```

И заменять pId и cId на необходимые Id в сервисе, но мне кажется это решение далеко не верное

Comment: Чтоб ответить на вопрос верное ли решение, нужно сначала сформулировать задачу. Какую задачу пытаетесь этим решить? Т.е. в каких случаях вам понадобиться менять этот параметр конфигурации?

Comment: @RomanKonoval понадобится в методе сервиса, который должен добавить параметр к телу запроса с этой ссылкой. т.е. у меня есть поле и аннотация Value, ссылающаяся на вот этот параметр, в методе я добавляю к телу запроса переменную с необходимым url и меняю параметры projectId и clientId на те, которые поступили на вход метода

Comment: Вы не ответили на мои вопросы. Зачем вам нужно выносить это в параметр конфигурации? Почему это не может быть константа в контроллере? Почему не годится динамически создавать url?

Comment: @RomanKonoval можно, но это унаследованной код и все такие константы с урлами содержатся в этом yaml файле

Comment: Вопрос и без этого дискуссионный, а так уж тем более. Если не знаем в чем задача, то как ответить правильное ли решение. Вердикт: нельзя дать объективный ответ